# Restrict published data to a public channel

Tags: pubnub, pam

I thought I understood what was going on here. But, apparently not. If I set up permissions like this, NO one receives published data.

```
{
    "channels": {
        "myChannel": {
            "auths": {
                "51EF3B88-3245-4CF1-B324-979F8E8A9EEF": {
                    "r": 1,
                    "w": 1
                },
                "F4EA7F64-27E3-4877-A86C-371FF7A9ABF2": {
                    "r": 1,
                    "w": 1
                }
            },
            "r": 0, // I thought this would turn OFF published data for the world
            "w": 0, // And the above auths would turn ON published data for the given keys
            "ttl": 1
        }
    },
    "subscribe_key": "my-sub-key",
    "level": "channel"
}
```

If I set it up like this, EVERYONE gets published data.

```
{
    "channels": {
        "myChannel": {
            "auths": {
                "51EF3B88-3245-4CF1-B324-979F8E8A9EEF": {
                    "r": 1,
                    "w": 1
                },
                "F4EA7F64-27E3-4877-A86C-371FF7A9ABF2": {
                    "r": 1,
                    "w": 1
                }
            },
            "r": 1, // this is the difference
            "w": 1, // this is the difference
        }
    },
    "subscribe_key": "my-sub-key",
    "level": "channel"
}
```

My test clients are Java. I have one setting an AuthKey to one of the above keys. The other is not setting an auth key. I can share that code if needed.

What am I not getting here?

**Edit**

Here are a couple code snippets. I am trying to set up a public channel for all users and then a private channel. What I see is clients that do not set a uuid can still see the published data.

The server permission setting code:

```
 pubnub = new Pubnub("myPubKey", "mySubKey", "mySecretKey");

 // the public channel
 pubnub.pamGrant("myChannel", true, true, ttl, callback);
 pubnub.pamGrant("myChannel", "F4EA7F64-27E3-4877-A86C-371FF7A9ABF2", true, true, ttl, callback);
 pubnub.pamGrant("myChannel", "51EF3B88-3245-4CF1-B324-979F8E8A9EEF", true, true, ttl, callback);

 // the private channels
 pubnub.pamGrant("F4EA7F64-27E3-4877-A86C-371FF7A9ABF2", "F4EA7F64-27E3-4877-A86C-371FF7A9ABF2", true, true, ttl, callback);
 pubnub.pamGrant("F4EA7F64-27E3-4877-A86C-371FF7A9ABF2", true, true, ttl, callback);

 pubnub.pamGrant("51EF3B88-3245-4CF1-B324-979F8E8A9EEF", "51EF3B88-3245-4CF1-B324-979F8E8A9EEF", true, true, ttl, callback);
 pubnub.pamGrant("51EF3B88-3245-4CF1-B324-979F8E8A9EEF", true, true, ttl, callback);
```

**Edit 2**

Here is my new attempt at granting permissions. This works, based on help from Craig.

```
  pubnub.pamGrant(Common.channelSummaries, Common.AuthKeyApp1, true, true, Common.ttl, callback);

  // grant read and write access to AuthKeyApp1 on the channel AuthKeyApp1 
  pubnub.pamGrant(Common.AuthKeyApp1, Common.AuthKeyApp1, true, true, Common.ttl, callback);

  // grant read and write access to serverUUID on the channel AuthKeyApp1 
  pubnub.pamGrant(Common.AuthKeyApp1, Common.serverUUID, true, true, Common.ttl, callback);

  pubnub.pamGrant(Common.channelSummaries, Common.AuthKeyApp2, true, true, Common.ttl, callback);

  // grant read and write access to AuthKeyApp1 on the channel AuthKeyApp1 
  pubnub.pamGrant(Common.AuthKeyApp2, Common.AuthKeyApp2, true, true, Common.ttl, callback);

  // grant read and write access to serverUUID on the channel AuthKeyApp1 
  pubnub.pamGrant(Common.AuthKeyApp2, Common.serverUUID, true, true, Common.ttl, callback);

  // grant read and write access to serverUUID on the channel channelNameGameSummaries 
  pubnub.pamGrant(Common.channelSummaries, Common.serverUUID, true, true, Common.ttl, callback);

  // grant read and write access to serverUUID on the channel channelNameGameSummariesPresense 
  pubnub.pamGrant(Common.channelSummariesPresense, Common.serverUUID, true, true, Common.ttl, callback);

  pubnub.pamGrant("", false, false, Common.ttl, callback);

  // Set the servers UUID to serverUUID  
  pubnub.setUUID(Common.serverUUID);
  pubnub.setAuthKey(Common.serverUUID);
```

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Scott, code would definitely hope. I only need to see the PubNub init/new code and the grant code.

Comment: Scott, just to provide some insights into what your code is probably doing (still need to see to confirm) is granting access to "myChannel" using two different auth-keys. And you are also granting access performing a grant at the channel level (no auth-key specified).

Comment: Craig, code posted as requested. One thing that confuses me though, is the permissions json I posted first. Those permission came from an audit of the channel in question. I would have thought that alone would clue me into what the actual permissions problem is. Is there a way to audit ALL permissions associated with a site?

Comment: re: all permissions, I answered my own question here. Do an audit with no channel.

Comment: next question regarding permissions (I would be happy to open a new SO to keep this thread clean), is there a way to simply expunge all existing permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott,

I know you answered it already but just to make this official, the issue is that you granted at the channel level then granted at the auth-key level. Access Manager grants are like CSS in reverse: the more general rule overrides the more specific. So the auth-key grant is specific to that auth-key and only users that init PubNub using that auth-key have those access rights.

But a channel level grant (no auth-key specified) opens the channel up to all users. No auth-key required. If true/true is granted on a particular channel, then it is like you turned Access Manager off for that one channel.

If you grant access true/true at the subscriber-key level, it is the same as disabling Access Manager completely. This is typically not useful for anything other than programatically disabling/enabling Access Manager (for whatever reason).

To remove a grant from an auth-key, channel or sub-key (in other words, revoke it), you just grant with false/false. So to revoke at the sub-key level. And in our Java SDK there are `revoke` methods (many SDKs just rely on `grant` with false/false access.

See details on our docs site: http://www.pubnub.com/docs/java/javase/api/reference.html#_pubnub_access_manager

That should just about wrap up all your questions above. Let me know if I missed anything.